# New Tab in Properties panel

Tags: python

How can I create a new tab (like the *World* or *Materials* tab) in the *Properties* window? It would be nice if I could choose a custom icon as well. I examined the blender python files and the documentation, but I don't know how to add a new button to the `spaceProperties` menu.

Comment: This can't be done via Python at the moment.

Comment: (i'm pretty sure this has been asked here before, but I can't find it.. )

Comment: ok, than I have to find a different way

Comment: You should create a new Panel in either the Scene, World, Object or Object Data tab. That should fit most needs.